# How can I add text or image for DataGridView on position -1, -1

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

How can I add text or image for DataGridView on position -1, -1, ex. in image[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `TopLeftHeaderCell` property of `DataGridview`. To set text use :

```
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "hello";
```